# If, for every $a \in \partial U$, $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = 0$, prove that there is at least a critical point of $f$ in $U$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Let $f: U \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function in the open $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$. If, for every $a \in \partial U$, $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = 0$, prove that there is at least a critical point of $f$ in $U$.

I don't know what to do. I cannot use $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = f(a)$ because $a \in \partial U$. I know that $a = \lim x_{n}$ with $x_{n} \in U$ and I'm trying to figure out how to use it. Before, I tried to show that $U$ has a maximum or minimum point, but I couldnot develop. Can someone help me?

Comment: The claim is false unless you have some additional condition on $U.$ For example, $f:U=\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}, x\to x$ has no critical points. Is $U$ bounded?

Comment: @mfl, thank you! The question is written as I announced, but is possible establish some condition (not too restrictive) over U so that this result is true?

Comment: As @JoséCarlosSantos said in a comment below the result holds if $U$ is bounded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true. Take $U=\{(x,y)\,|\,x>0\}$ and let $f(x,y)=x$. Then $\partial U=\{(0,y)\,|\,y\in\mathbb{R}\}$ and$$(\forall a\in\partial U):\lim_{X\to a}f(X)=0.$$However, $f$ has no critical point.

Comment: Thank you! Is possible establish some condition (not too restrictive) over $U$ so that this result is true?

Comment: @LucasCorrêa Sure. If $U$ is bounded, then the statement is true.

Comment: Assuming that $U$ is bounded, I can ensure, at least, that there is critical points in $\partial U$. How can I use $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = 0$ (if $a$ is the maximum or minimum, for example) for show that $f$ has a critical points in $U$?

Comment: @LucasCorrêa Extend $f$ to $\overline U$ defining $f(p)=0$ when $p\in\partial U$. Then $f$ is a continuous function with compact domain. If it is the null function, then *all* points of $U$ is a critical point. Otherwise, eith the maximum of f$ is positive or the minimum is negative. Take the point at which the maximum or the minimum is attained.

Answer (score 1):

If $U$ is bounded, then it is possible to extend $f$ to the boundary, using the condition, so that the extension is still continuous (define it as $0$ on the boundary). The domain of the extended function is still bounded, so the extended function attains its maximum $M$ and minimum $m$. If $M=m=0$, then $f=0$, so it has critical points (every point of $U$). 
So WLOG assume that $M>0$. Then the maximum is attained at a point of $U$, so it has to be a critical point of $f$.